# Wordpress: stuck after installing Wordpress and copying in wp-content directory

Tags: php, wordpress

Completely new to Wordpress and I am working on a collaborative project however I am having trouble getting up and running.

This is what I have done so far...

1. Installed MAMP.
2. Went to PHPmyadmin and created a database (e.g. myblog).
3. Downloaded Wordpress.
4. Copied and pasted existing wp-content into my downloaded Wordpress folder in htdocs and also renamed that folder from 'wordpress' to '/myblog'.
5. Went to localhost selected /myblog.
6. Installed Wordpress
7. Went to dashboard click visit site.

Now getting Not Found

The requested URL /myblog/lessons/orientation/ was not found on this server.

Would anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: *`"Would anyone know what I am doing wrong here"`* <- You're using a Mac ?

Comment: The requested URL is already rewritten url (and it is not default wp behavior), check your .htaccess (which should be automatically created when you change settings in dashboard)?

Comment: first check that either you have url_rewirte module is enable or not? have you Copied same version that you copied from?

Comment: Yes I am using a Mac @adeneo

Comment: I don't have a .htaccess file. I tried activating a plugin to see if it would show up but, nothing. Should I just make it? Or would that cause any conflictions later on since the file is created automatically? @nevermind

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the [htaccess rewrite rules for WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) to your MAMP server. Without these rewrite rules, the browser request doesn't actually get routed to be handled by WordPress.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

In MAMP, you have to add these rules in the MAMP app itself and not in an .htaccess file (unless you specifically configure MAMP to allow that).

Here is a screenshot of where to do that in MAMP 2, the field is called "Customized Virtual Host Directory Settings"

[image]

Comment: tried that, doesn't work. Also I am using MAMP 3. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Dashboard>Settings>Permalinks try changing your permalink setting.